# What does the weight stat on weapons mean?

Tags: stardew-valley

Some of the weapons in Stardew Valley have a `+ Weight` stat. For instance, the Claymore sword has +3 weight. What, if anything, does this stat affect? Does using a weapon of this type make my character stronger? Is it just an indication that the weapon is slower to swing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's knockback

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, but for the sake of completeness and since now they are available, here are links from 2 wikis confirming this and giving the weight stats for all the weapons:

http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Weight

http://stardewvalley.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can say after testing that it is knockback. I have used a Crystal Dagger which had weight 5. And most bats and especially ghosts where pretty much just knocked out of the screen.

It feels to me like beeing planed as advantage but in my opinion its actually a disadvantage.

I returned to even a weaker weapon without weight and getting along better with it.

So I can confirm as allready mentioned: weight means knockback.

Comment: I've found that ghosts and slimes are very very light and will suffer the most knockback of any monster as well.

Comment: @ChaseC: I presumed that here :)

Comment: I'm just happy that the death occurs before the knockback, and the mats aren't stuck in a wall.

Comment: @HireThisMarine: With said dagger I had exactly that case. a golden star mob I encoutnered dropped his items on the top of a wall so I couldn't collect it and it were some boots I haven't seen before.... Was unable to pick em up. Thats when I changed using the,....

Comment: The Magnet Ring is really really useful for that, and I've honestly stopped wearing anything else. Glow Ring and Magnet Ring seems to be the best combo for me.

Comment: When you have three or four Serpents in the Skull Caverns swarming you, you might look at knockback more sympathetically.